# NetBeans error while scanning a text file

Tags: java, file

Im jus trying to assign the double score1 to the first double of my text file, but I get this error which I have never gotten before:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at skatersdemo.SkatersDemo.main(SkatersDemo.java:28)
D:\JAVA 1\LABS\SkatersDemo\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1328: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\JAVA 1\LABS\SkatersDemo\nbproject\build-impl.xml:948: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)**
```

My code is the following:

```
***File inputFile = new File("D:\\JAVA 1\\LABS\\SkatersDemo\\Final_Project\\Pairs.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

        Skaters[] skatersArray = new Skaters[10];
        double[] scores = new double[160];
        int counter=0;

        double score1 = input.nextDouble();


        System.out.println(score1);***
```

Additionally here is the beginning of the text file:

```
smith
jones
australia
4.2 5.1 3.8 2.9 5.0 4.6 4.9 4.3
4.9 4.8 5.8 3.8 4.9 4.6 5.0 4.5
```

Comment: The errors does not come from Netbean that's just an IDE. Reading a string with nextDouble ? sure ?

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
double score1 = input.nextDouble();
```

but the text file does not start with a double, but with a string.

`Scanner::nextDouble` throws an `InputMismatchException` *if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range* as per the [Java Platform Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble())

You might want to consider using `Scanner::nextLine` to scan the first three lines and only then start to scan doubles.

Comment: is there a way for me to scan the file only for doubles and ignore the Strings? Because the strings reoccur in the file, there are 3 lines with names then 2 lines with doubles and so on. Also, later on I have to scan only the names but when I use ***input.next()*** it considers 4.5 as a String

Comment: You can skip lines with `Scanner::nextLine` also, simply don't save the return value to anywhere.